# vector and span

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $u_1,u_2,u_3$, and $v$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the RREF of $(u_1 |u_2 |u_3 |v)$ is \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1&1\\0&1&2&-2\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}(This is a consistent linear system) Can I conclude that $v$ is in $span\{u1,u2,u3\}$ since it is a linear combination of the three vectors above. And by making $u_3$ an arbitrarily chosen parameter, can I say that the general solution of v is $v=(1+s)u_1−2(1+s)u_2+su_3$ for any $s\in \mathbb{R}$. If not, how to express v in terms of u1,u2,u3 in an equation?

Comment: See [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to typeset mathematics here.

Comment: Being "a linear combination of the vectors" is pretty much the **definition** of "being in the span"!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $v = -u_3\implies v\in span(u_1,u_2,u_3)$.

This is a direct conclusion of the properties of span (actually by definition).

Comment: So is  the general solution  v=(1+s)u1−2(1+s)u2+su3 ??  in this case, let say u3=s, then u2+2s=-2 so u2=-2-2s then similarly u1=1+s   is this right?